# Output name of column with max value per line

Tags: awk

I have

```
chr pos C T A G
NC_044998.1     3732    21 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3733    22 0 2 0
NC_044998.1     3734    22 0 5 0
NC_044998.1     3735    22 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3736    0 0 7 0
NC_044998.1     3737    0 0 0 22
NC_044998.1     3738    20 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3739    1 0 22 0
NC_044998.1     3740    0 22 0 0
NC_044998.1     3741    22 0 0 0
```

I need to output the max value in $3 to $7 per line as well as the column name associated with it.

so that I have

```
chr pos max ref
NC_044998.1     3732 21 C
NC_044998.1     3733 22 C
NC_044998.1     3734 22 C
NC_044998.1     3735 22 C
NC_044998.1     3736 7 A
NC_044998.1     3737 22 G
NC_044998.1     3738 20 C
NC_044998.1     3739 22 A
NC_044998.1     3740 22 T
NC_044998.1     3741 22 C
```

I'm trying to adapt this:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {for (c = 3; c <= NF; i++) headers[c] = $c; next} {maxc=3;for(c=4;c<=NF;c++)if($c>$maxc){maxc=c} printf "max:%s, %s\n", $maxc, headers[maxc]}'
```

but it just output this max value

also have tried

```
awk '{maxc=3;for(c=4;c<=NF;c++)if($c>$maxc){maxc=c; $maxc = headers[c]} printf "max:%s, column:%s, column:%s\n",$maxc, maxc, headers[maxc]}'
```

Another issue I'm trying to figure is in cases where there's a tie between one or more columns. In that case I would like to print the max and the names of all columns associated.

Comment: You say `I need to output the max value in $3 to $7` but there's no $7 in your input or your output so please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by that or otherwise fix your question.

Comment: Regarding `Another issue...` - don't just add something significant like that as a sentence at the end of your question, include it in your sample input/output if you want that case to be part of the solution. I didn't notice that statement til after I saw that one of the other answers had taken it into account and now I don't know what you want the output to look like if that case occurs as there's multiple ways we could `print the max and the names of all columns associated`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v startField="3" -v endField="6" '
FNR==1{
  for(i=startField;i<=endField;i++){
    heading[i]=$i
  }
  next
}
{
  max=maxInd=""
  for(i=startField;i<=endField;i++){
    maxInd=(max<$i?i:maxInd)
    max=(max<$i?$i:max)
  }
  NF=(startField-1)
  print $0,heading[maxInd]
}
'  Input_file
```

***Advantages of this code's approach:***

- user can mention starting field number and ending field number by using variables named `startField` and `endField` so we need NOT to change anything inside main `awk` code.
- 2nd advantage is since nothing is hardcoded here, so lets say User tomorrow wants to check maximum values from 10th field to 20th field then we need NOT to print or mention explicitly 9th fields to get printed since that is taken care in code itself.

***Detailed explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v startField="3" -v endField="6" '   ##Starting awk program and setting startField and endField to values on which user wants to look for maximum values.
FNR==1{                                   ##Checking condition if this is first line of Input_file.
  for(i=startField;i<=endField;i++){      ##Traversing through only those fields which user needs to get max value.
    heading[i]=$i                         ##Creating array heading whose index is i and value is current field value.
  }
  next                                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  max=maxInd=""                           ##Nullifying max and maxInd variables here.
  for(i=startField;i<=endField;i++){      ##Traversing through only those fields which user needs to get max value.
    maxInd=(max<$i?i:maxInd)              ##Getting maxInd variable to current field number if current field value is greater than maxInd else keep it as maxInd itself.
    max=(max<$i?$i:max)                   ##Getting max variable to current field value if current field value is greater than max else keep it as max itself.
  }
  NF=(startField-1)                       ##Setting NF(number of fields of current line) to startField-1 here.
  print $0,heading[maxInd]                ##printing current field followed by heading array value whose index is maxInd.
}
'  Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 4):

For your original desired outcome:

```
awk 'NR==1 {for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) header_array[i] = $i; } NR>1{a=$3; for (i=3;i<=6;i++) if($i >= a) {a=$i; column=header_array[i]} {printf "max:%s, %s\n", a, column}}' file

# Output
max:21, C
max:22, C
max:22, C
max:22, C
max:7, A
max:22, G
max:20, C
max:22, A
max:22, T
max:22, C
```

For your updated desired outcome:

```
awk 'NR==1 {for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) header_array[i] = $i; print "chr pos max ref"} NR>1{char=$1; pos=$2; a=$3; for (i=3;i<=6;i++) if($i >= a) {a=$i; column=header_array[i]} {printf "%s %s %s %s\n", char, pos, a, column}}' file

# Output
chr pos max ref
NC_044998.1 3732 21 C
NC_044998.1 3733 22 C
NC_044998.1 3734 22 C
NC_044998.1 3735 22 C
NC_044998.1 3736 7 A
NC_044998.1 3737 22 G
NC_044998.1 3738 20 C
NC_044998.1 3739 22 A
NC_044998.1 3740 22 T
NC_044998.1 3741 22 C
```

Formatted:

```
awk 'NR==1 {
    for (i = 0; i <= NF; i++) {
        header_array[i] = $i
        }
    print "chr pos max ref"
    }
    NR>1 {
        char = $1
        pos = $2
        a = $3
        for (i = 3; i <= 6; i++) {
            if ($i >= a) {
                a = $i
                column = header_array[i]
            }
        } {
           printf "%s %s %s %s\n", char, pos, a, column
        }
    }' file
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for updating it on the go like that. It won't happen again

Comment: That's ok, thanks for apologising. I can see you've added another requirement for dealing with ties since I last logged on; if you need to keep expanding your code to address edge cases and/or additional requirements it might be worth investigating more flexible scripting languages (e.g python, which has packages like biopython/seqIO). There may also be specific bioinformatics software suitable for your task which greatly reduces the chance of unforeseen errors and 'gotchas'; the folks over at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ can probably help you.

Answer (score 3):

you can try it

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";FS="[[:space:]]+"}
     NR==1{print $1,$2,"max","ref"; 
           for(i=3;i<=6;++i)BASES[i]=$(i);
     } 
     NR>1{
        basemax=3; max=$3;
        for(i=4;i<=6;++i){if($i>max){basemax=i;max=$i;}}
        print $1,$2,BASES[basemax],max
     }
' inputfile
```

you get,

```
chr pos max ref
NC_044998.1 3732    C   21
NC_044998.1 3733    C   22
NC_044998.1 3734    C   22
NC_044998.1 3735    C   22
NC_044998.1 3736    A   7
NC_044998.1 3737    G   22
NC_044998.1 3738    C   20
NC_044998.1 3739    A   22
NC_044998.1 3740    T   22
NC_044998.1 3741    C   22
```

**NOTE: If exist two or more bases with max value, correction**

For input,

```
chr pos C T A G
NC_044998.1     3732    21 0 21 0
NC_044998.1     3733    22 0 2 0
NC_044998.1     3734    22 0 5 0
NC_044998.1     3735    22 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3736    0 0 7 7
NC_044998.1     3737    0 0 0 22
NC_044998.1     3738    20 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3739    1 0 22 0
NC_044998.1     3740    0 22 0 0
NC_044998.1     3741    22 0 0 0
```

you can try it

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";FS="[[:space:]]+"}
     NR==1{print $1,$2,"max","ref"; 
         for(i=3;i<=6;++i)BASES[i]=$(i);
     } 
     NR>1{basemax=BASES[3]; max=$3;
         for(i=4;i<=6;++i){
             if($i>max){basemax=BASES[i];max=$i;}
             else if($i==max){basemax=basemax","BASES[i];}
         }
         print $1,$2,basemax,max
     }
' fileinput
```

you get,

```
chr pos max ref
NC_044998.1 3732    C,A 21
NC_044998.1 3733    C   22
NC_044998.1 3734    C   22
NC_044998.1 3735    C   22
NC_044998.1 3736    A,G 7
NC_044998.1 3737    G   22
NC_044998.1 3738    C   20
NC_044998.1 3739    A   22
NC_044998.1 3740    T   22
NC_044998.1 3741    C   22
```

Comment: Thank you! Why this doesn't work for setting: for(i=4;i<=6;++i){
             if($i<min){basemmin=BASES[i];mim=$i;}
             else if($i==min){basemin=basemin","BASES[i];++l}

Comment: or setting          for(i=4;i<=6;++i){
             if($i<min){basemmin=BASES[i];mim=$i;}
             else if($i==min){basemin=basemin","BASES[i];++l}. Both settinh min=$3

Comment: mim is different of min variable

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have this input file:

```sh
cat file

chr pos C T A G
NC_044998.1     3732    21 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3733    22 0 2 0
NC_044998.1     3734    22 0 5 0
NC_044998.1     3735    22 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3736    0 0 7 7
NC_044998.1     3737    0 22 0 22
NC_044998.1     3738    20 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3739    1 0 22 0
NC_044998.1     3740    0 22 0 0
NC_044998.1     3741    22 0 0 0
```

TO get your desired output, use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v b=3 'NR==1{for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i) hdr[i]=$i; print $1, $2, "max", "ref"; next} {for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i) max=($i>max?$i:max); for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i == max) c4=(c4?c4 ";":"") hdr[i]; print $1, $2, max, c4; max=c4=""}' file

chr pos max ref
NC_044998.1 3732 21 C
NC_044998.1 3733 22 C
NC_044998.1 3734 22 C
NC_044998.1 3735 22 C
NC_044998.1 3736 7 A;G
NC_044998.1 3737 22 T;G
NC_044998.1 3738 20 C
NC_044998.1 3739 22 A
NC_044998.1 3740 22 T
NC_044998.1 3741 22 C
```

Here is a more readable version:

```sh
awk -v b=3 '
NR == 1 {
   for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i)
      hdr[i] = $i
   print $1, $2, "max", "ref"
   next
}
{
   for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i)
      max = ($i > max ? $i : max)
   for (i=b; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i == max)
         c4 = (c4 ? c4 ";" : "") hdr[i]
   print $1, $2, max, c4
   max=c4=""
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Given this input file with duplicate max values on the 1st and 6th data lines:

```
$ cat file
chr pos C T A G
NC_044998.1     3732    21 0 21 0
NC_044998.1     3733    22 0 2 0
NC_044998.1     3734    22 0 5 0
NC_044998.1     3735    22 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3736    0 0 7 0
NC_044998.1     3737    0 22 0 22
NC_044998.1     3738    20 0 0 0
NC_044998.1     3739    1 0 22 0
NC_044998.1     3740    0 22 0 0
NC_044998.1     3741    22 0 0 0
```

Using GNU awk for `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
}
{
    printf "%s%s%s%s", $1, OFS, $2, OFS
    $1 = $2 = ""
}
NR==1 {
    split($0,refs)
    print "max", "ref"
    next
}
{
    n = split($0,vals)

    for ( i in vals ) {
        maxVal = vals[i]
        break
    }

    ref = sep = ""
    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
        if ( vals[i] == maxVal ) {
            ref = ref sep refs[i]
            sep = ","
        }
    }

    print maxVal, ref
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
chr          pos   max  ref
NC_044998.1  3732  21   C,A
NC_044998.1  3733  22   C
NC_044998.1  3734  22   C
NC_044998.1  3735  22   C
NC_044998.1  3736  7    A
NC_044998.1  3737  22   T,G
NC_044998.1  3738  20   C
NC_044998.1  3739  22   A
NC_044998.1  3740  22   T
NC_044998.1  3741  22   C
```

The main reason I posted the above is to show how to get a min or max by using "sorted_in" along with `for ( i in ... )` and then breaking after accessing the first index as that would then give you the max or min based on whatever criteria you set using `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]=...` without you having to write any code to do the comparisons.

Comment: Interesting! So, to look for the min instead of max one would just need to change it to "@val_num_asc"?

Comment: Oh wow it does!

Comment: How do I exclude 0s from the min counts? I tried adding this but it didnt work: for ( i in vals ) {
        if (vals[i] != 0){
        maxVal = vals[i] }
        break

Comment: You'd need to put the break inside the if, not outside it.